# Inserir conteudo do ListView no banco de dados (MySQL)

Tags: vb.net

Ola, estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação em vb e gostaria de saber, como passar uma lista criada no controle ListViw para o banco de dados?
até o momento construi isso:

```
  Private Sub criarLista()
    ListView1.Clear()
    ListView1.View = View.Details
    ListView1.LabelEdit = True
    ListView1.AllowColumnReorder = True
    ListView1.CheckBoxes = True
    ListView1.FullRowSelect = True
    ListView1.GridLines = True
    ListView1.Sorting = SortOrder.Ascending

    If btnInclusao.BackColor = Color.Silver Then
        With ListView1
            .Columns.Add("Codigo da Coleta", 120, HorizontalAlignment.Left)
            .Columns.Add("Observações", 120, HorizontalAlignment.Left)
        End With
    End If

    If btnManutencao.BackColor = Color.Silver Then
        With ListView1
            .Columns.Add("Codigo da Coleta", 120, HorizontalAlignment.Left)
            .Columns.Add("Observações", 120, HorizontalAlignment.Left)
            .Columns.Add("Baixa da Coleta", 120, HorizontalAlignment.Left)
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

o codigo que add os itens dentro da lista:

```
  Dim newItem As New ListViewItem(CodColeta_txt.Text)
  newItem.SubItems.Add(obsColeta_txt.Text)
```

Tentei fazer dessa forma:

```
    Private Sub inserirListadeColeta()
     reconect()

    For Each item As ListViewItem In ListView1.Items
        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO ListaParaColeta (fk_ColetaParaMotorista, ListaParaColeta_CodColeta, ListaParaColeta_osbColeta" _
        & "ListaParaColeta_periodo, ListaParaColeta_dataRegistro) VALUES (@fk, @CodColeta, @obsColeta, @periodo, @data) "
        Using conn
            Using cmd
                With cmd
                    .Connection = conn
                    .CommandType = CommandType.Text
                    .Parameters.Add("@fk", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = codParaMotorista
                    .Parameters.Add("@CodColeta", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = item.SubItems(0).Text 'Campo do ListViwer Codigo da Coleta
                    .Parameters.Add("@obsColeta", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = item.SubItems(1).Text ' Campo do ListViwer OBS
                    .Parameters.Add("@periodo", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = cmbPeriodo.SelectedIndex
                    .Parameters.Add("@data", MySqlDbType.Date).Value = Format(DataHoje.Value, "yyyyMMdd")
                End With
                Try
                    cmd.ExecuteReader()
                    Clipboard.Clear()
                    Clipboard.SetText(strsql)
                    MsgBox("inserirListadeColeta")

                Catch ex As Exception
                    MsgBox("Erro inserirListadeColeta" & vbCrLf & ex.ToString, MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Erro")
                    Clipboard.Clear()
                    Clipboard.SetText(strsql)
                    Exit Sub
                End Try
            End Using
        End Using
    Next
End Sub
```

Desde já agradeço!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolvi...

```
    Dim qntItens As Integer
    Dim qntLops As Integer
    Dim objlistViwer
    reconect()
    qntItens = ListView1.Items.Count
    If Not ListView1.Items.Count = 0 Then
        Do Until qntLops = ListView1.Items.Count
            objlistViwer = ListView1.Items.Item(qntLops)
            With objlistViwer
                cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO listaparacoleta (fk_ColetaParaMotorista, ListaParaColeta_CodColeta,ListaParaColeta_obsColeta, ListaParaColeta_periodo,ListaParaColeta_DataRegistro) VALUES" _
                    & "('" & codParaMotorista & "','" & lvitem.subitems(0).text & "','" & lvitem.subitems(1).text & "','" & cmbPeriodo.SelectedIndex & "','" & Format(DataHoje.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")) & "')"
                Try
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                Catch ex As Exception
                    MsgBox("Erro inserirListadeColeta" & vbCrLf & ex.ToString, MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Erro")
                    Exit Sub
                End Try
            End With
            qntLops = qntLops + 1
            objlistViwer = Nothing
        Loop
        MsgBox("Dados Enviados!")
    End If
```

para recupera-los:

```
    criarLista()
    reconect()
    Dim dr_temp As MySqlDataReader
    strsql = "Comando SQL que ID seja = '" & codFKColeta & "'"
    Dim objCommand As New MySqlCommand(strsql, conn)
    Try
        dr_temp = objCommand.ExecuteReader()
    Catch ex As Exception
        Exit Sub
    End Try
    ListView1.BeginUpdate()
    While (dr_temp.Read())
        Dim codigos As String = dr_temp.Item(1)
        Dim ls As New ListViewItem(codigos, 0)
        ls.SubItems.Add(dr_temp.Item(2))
        ls.SubItems.Add(dr_temp.Item(3))
        ListView1.Items.Add(ls)
    End While
    ListView1.EndUpdate()
```